# How do you remove elements when changing scenes?

Tags: coronasdk

In a space shooter, I add enemies through a separate LUA file. These enemies have timers that create shots. When changing scenes, I want to remove all instances of enemies, stop their timers and remove all shots.

I have been able to remove the individual enemies by adding them to the scene's display group, but I can't do that with the timers or the shots.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

While creating a timer, just do as follows:

declare the timer at the top of you scene to get it a global scope on the scene, as:

```
local timer_1
```

Then use the timer as:

```
timer_1 = timer.performWithDelay(1000,myFunction,-1)
```

Then you can stop it as:

```
if(timer_1)then
  timer.cancel(timer_1)
end
```

Keep coding.................. :)

Comment: Problem is, the timers are declared in the class that creates the enemies, not in the scene. In the scene, I call for the enemies and pass unique timer handles for each enemy through parameters. If I declare timers globally in the enemy class, they will all shoot simultaneously, as they'll run on the same timer.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do (and that's how i handle this kind of issue in my game actually) is create a table to keep track of the enemies, then make it so enemies are object oriented classes owning both the timers and the shots.

Example:

You could create an 'enemy' class (local myEnemy) which has an internal timer (myEnemy.timerID) and an internal table of shots fired (myEnemy.shots).

Even better, add a 'destroy' method to the enemy (myEnemy.destroy()) that stops the timers and destroys the shot, then when you change scene you just have to iterate through your table, call the destroy method on each enemy, and timers / shots will be destroyed automatically :)

I don't know if your code is object oriented already but in this kind of case it makes things a lot easier :)
Let me know if you need anymore info

Cheers